# Getting value from a list corresponding to another list

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing:

```
NewL = [(1.1,[01,02]),(1.2,[03,04]),(1.3,[05,06])]
```

and i used enumerate to obtain the list as above where the square brackets containing [01,02],[03,04] and [05,06] are generally obtained from another list. I'll show it just in case:

```
L = [[01,02],[03,04],[05,06]]
```

and initially the output list is just:

```
OutputList = [1.1,1.2,1.3]
```

i used enumerate on both of this list to get what i have as the first list i've written above.

The problem i'm facing now is, let's say i want to only output the value for [05,06] which is 1.3 from the NewL. How would i do that? I was thinking of something like:

```
for val in NewL:
    if NewL[1] == [05,06]:
        print NewL[0]
```

but it's totally wrong as cases might change where it's not necessary always be [05,06] as it can be obtaining value for [03,04] and [01,02] too. I'm pretty new using enumerate so I'll appreciate any help for this.

Comment: What is the question ? Given one 2 member list from `L`, you want to be able to obtain the float from `OutputList` at the same index ?

Comment: you can use `dic` here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop should like this:

```
for val in NewL:
    if val[1] == [5,6]:
            print val[0]
```

It will print `1.3`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, so I will extrapolate what you need:

Given your 2 intial lists:

```
L = [[01,02],[03,04],[05,06]]
OutputList = [1.1,1.2,1.3]
```

you can generate your transformed list using:

```
NewL = list(zip(OutputList, L))
```

then, given 1 item from `L`, if you want to retrieve the value from `OutputList`:

```
val = [x for x, y in NewL if y == [05,06]][0]
```

But it would be a lot easier to just do:

```
val = OutputList[L.index([05,06])]
```

Note that both those expressions will raise an `IndexError` if the searched item is not found